# What would be last address in 31 bit scheme

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I have a register which 31 bit wide ,Now I am confused between two number that could be used as last address 31 bit scheme .

Would  0x7fff-fffc or 0x80000000 be the last address can be used in 31 scheme.

Comment: 0x7fff-ffff for byte addresses.

Comment: yep 7FFFFFFF is 31 bits all set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addresses start at zero. So `0x7FFFFFFF` if you are addressing bytes. `0x7FFFFFFC` if you are addressing 32-bit words.

Comment: Thanks mbratch for the answer ,would you please explain your point of 0x7FFFFFFF if you are addressing bytes and 0x7FFFFFFC if you are addressing 32-bit words.,I mean how they are different.

Comment: @Amit if we're talking hardware, then you put an address on the buss and you get a value back from memory. If your memory is 32-bit addressable, then the highest 32-bit *word* address is `0x7FFF FFFC`. If you are addressing bytes and getting back an 8-bit value, then you would use `0x7FFF FFFF`. It all depends upon what the hardware supports. If they were 16-bit words, then the highest address would be `0x7FFF FFFE`. I may not be totally comprehending your purpose in the question. :)

Comment: @Amit or, in other words, if you are accessing 32 data bits at `0x7ffffffc`, the hardware accesses the four bytes at `0x7ffffffc`, `0x7ffffffd`, `0x7ffffffe` and `0x7fffffff`

Comment: ok fine @mbratch ,is there any way for me to find out H/W support 16 bit words or 32 bit or all I have to do is to look into the H/W specs

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar You would need to look at the specs of your specific HW platform.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas for making this point,It made the picture bit more clearer for me.

Answer (score 1):

> Would 0x7fff-fffc or 0x80000000 be the last address can be used in 31 scheme.

Neither of them - the last address is  `0x7fffffff` (not `c`). For `0x80000000` you already need the 32nd bit to be set.

As @mbratch points out, `0x7ffffffc` would be the last address if you are addressing 32 bit words, or similarly `0x7ffffffe` if you are addressing 16 bit words.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an address is only used to reference 4 hunks of memory (like bytes), 7ffffffc is the last one.

Usually we address memory in 8-bit bytes but there is no inherent need to do so. Any number of bytes can go into a thing that is addressable.

Then, we have developed a convention that we assign addresses to each byte but only load memory in blocks of 2 or 4 (or whatever number) and so we build the hardware to ignore the last 1 or 2 or whatever few address lines.

The value 80000000 does not fit in 31 bits.

The value 7fffffff does fit in 31 bytes and can be used if you may address a single byte of memory.

The value 7ffffffc also fits in 31 bytes and would be used if you may only address bytes in aligned chunks of 4 bytes at a time.